# Why is this std::unique_ptr being returned without a std::move statement

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to familiarize my self with the `std::unique_ptr` and I understand that these pointers can only be moved. This is the code that I am trying out

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
};

std::unique_ptr<foo> GetPointer()
{
    std::unique_ptr<foo> f(new foo());
    return f;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<foo> m = GetPointer();
}
```

I am using the flag `-fno-elide-constructors` to disable compiler optimization that reduces the copies made. My question is why is the `f` being returned ? It is an lvalue so I am assuming it cannot be moved. I was expecting to get an error because of `return f` and I was under the impression it should be return `std::move(f)`

Comment: I am trying this out on coliru with the following `g++ -std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out`

Comment: This is also covered as part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11540204/962089), which has a ton of information on move semantics if you need it.

Comment: @chris I don't think the question is just about moving a unique pointer. It looks like the OP wanted this to *fail*, and tried to make it so via disabling elided constructions, yet it still works. Further, the linked duplicate's selected answer beautifully covers copy elision and rvo, but again, it looks like the OP was trying *not* to do that.

Comment: Yes i was expecting to get a compilation error however the above code compiled successfully. Why is that ?

Comment: @MistyD The answer chris linked is amazing. Scroll down to the `Moving out of functions` section.

Comment: @WhozCraig, The section you stated really does spectacularly cover why this fails. *If a function returns by value, some object at call site is initialized with the expression after the return statement as an argument to the move constructor* and *C++11 has a special rule that allows returning automatic objects from functions without having to write std::move* in particular.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Yes that explains it. Now I wonder if `-fno-elide-constructors` works only with copy constructors and does not affect move semantics

Comment: @MistyD, The compiler can still elide moves. Returning a large `std::array` by value works much better with an elided move because moving a `std::array` still requires copying everything.

Comment: @chris Joseph M. touches on it as well in a comment under the selected answer linked as a duplicate here, but the answer you linked (authored by fred as well, go figure) is absolutely amazing. Thanks for that!. That thing should be a chapter in a book somewhere.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I suppose that's what you get from someone who actually teaches :)